# SSRS: How do you collect small series in a stack chart?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Pie charts seem to have this ability of grouping small series together into an "Other" group.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/collect-small-slices-on-a-pie-chart-report-builder-and-ssrs

How would you do this for a stack chart?

I'm working from a dataset that calls a stored procedure, which I have no access to (I don't have the password). I actually have to deploy the report to even test it, so manipulating the SQL is out of the question.

Thanks!

Comment: You can always select (`insert into ...exec...`) the results of a stored procedure into a temp table, change the data in the temp table to provide what you need, and use the temp table data in the report.

Comment: @R.Richards is correct. It will be much easier to do in the dataset query using the method he describes. Doing this in the report designer is probably possible but just not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Changing the dataset refreshes the fields and since I can't access the dataset while in Visual Studio, all the fields disappear.

Comment: It's possible to edit the .rdl file in a text editor and change the dataset section to use a select statement instead of a stored procedure. I was having difficulty getting a simpler insert into #tmp ..exec.. to work. Declaring a table variable and inserting into that worked better.